# VBA Compare two Workbooks, if no Match, Copy/Highlight

Tags: vba, excel

I've been toying with some code and I can't, for the life of me, get it to do exactly what I want it to do. I would like it to Compare WB1(Master) to WB2(Daily), if new records found in WB2, highlight the entire row and copy(append) all new rows over to WB1. The code I have right now highlights all the new data in WB2 but it will only copy the last new row from WB2 to WB1. I'm sure I'm missing something simple but would appreciate the 2nd set of eyes. Thank you!

```
Sub compare_files()

Dim c As Range
Dim masterWB, dailyWB As Workbook
Dim mWS, dWS As Worksheet
Dim lRow, lRow2 As Long

Set masterWB = Workbooks.Open("masterFile.xlsx")
Set dailyWB = Workbooks("dailyFile.xlsx")
Set mWS = masterWB.Sheets(1)
Set dWS = dailyWB.Sheets(1)

'remove useless columns first
dWS.Columns("C:D").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
dWS.Columns("D:F").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
dWS.Columns("G:K").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
dWS.Columns("H:I").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
dWS.Columns("I:K").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
dWS.Columns("O:AR").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
dWS.Columns("P:W").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
dWS.Columns("Q").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
dWS.Columns("T").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
dWS.Columns("AB:AI").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

'sort Certified Timestamp Column TopToBottom
dWS.ListObjects("Table1").Sort. _
    SortFields.Clear
dWS.ListObjects("Table1").Sort. _
    SortFields.add Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Certified Timestamp]]"), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
With dWS.ListObjects("Table1").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

lRow = mWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lRow1 = dWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In dWS.Range("A2", dWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

If Not c.Value = mWS.Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Value Then
    c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    c.EntireRow.Copy mWS.Range("A" & lRow)

End If

Next c

mWS.Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating your "lrow" variable in your For loop after pasting a new row, so you are likely pasting over the same location every time.

Reassign "lrow" in your If Not statement to account for newly added rows.

```
For Each c In dWS.Range("A2", dWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

If Not c.Value = mWS.Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Value Then
    c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    c.EntireRow.Copy mWS.Range("A" & lRow)
    lRow = mWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


End If

Next c
```

Does that solve it?

EDIT: As pointed out below, .Cells.End.xlUp finds the last occupied row. You need to increment lrow+1 to point to the first *empty* row.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and it was still doing just the single row. However, instead of your line, I add `lRow = lRow + 1`

Comment: `mWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` is the *last occupied row* (at least, based on what's in ColA), not the first empty row: adding 1 fixes that

Comment: Ah yes, good call. Increment to find the empty row. Glad you were able to bridge the gap :)

Comment: Also, make sure you aren't overwriting the last populated row in your mWS worksheet on your first Copy/Paste operation since you aren't incrementing "lRow" from the beginning. (At least as your code currently stands.)